# How to calculate cpu utilization on DVFS CPU with multi-cores

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

usually we calculate cpu usage by

wall times  of tasks /   (wall times * cpu cores)

however, moderm cpu is DVFS,  90% cpu usage doesn't mean use 90% of cpu caculation power.

we should calculate utilication of cpu caculation capacity.

how to do that?